# Generate random distribution

Tags: math, random, statistics, distribution

I need to generate the following random distribution:

200 persons and 250 entities of types A and B:

- 75% persons have entities of type A
- 10% persons have entities of type B
- 15% persons have 2 entities of type B

Is it possible to generate such random distribution?

Comment: "at least", "at most", "exactly", "only A", "only B", "A and possibly B", ... This kind of information seems to be missing from your question.

Comment: "unknown number of A and unknown number of B, 250 in total" ?

Comment: Most important thing is that an entity belongs to the user and they have to be distributed across them in the following way: 

75% of persons have N entities of type A, 10% of persons have M entities of type B, 15% of persons have multiple(2) entities = (P entities) of type B. N + M + P = 250.

Comment: `200*(.75) + 200 * (.1) + 2(200)(.15) = 230` not `250`. Your numbers don't add up. In any event, the notion of "random" and the notion of "exact distribution" typically don't mix well.

Comment: One person can have multiple entities..

Comment: Please edit additional useful information into the question, instead of "hiding" it among the comments. Have another look at [ask], please. Maybe also at https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: People from the 75% have at least one A, can they also have B? Can people from the 75% (having at least one A) also belong to the 10% (having also at least one B)? Can people from the 75% belong to the 15% (having exactly 2 B)? Do the 10% people belong to the 15% (having exactly 2 B is a special case of having at least one B). Can people from the 10% (with at least one B) belong to the 75% (also having at least one a)? If any of that is "yes", then there can be quite some people without either A or B, true?

Comment: Please provide a few examples of valid situations. E.g. make lists like "20 people have neither A or B; 20 people have one A, no B; ..." and demonstrate how they fit the given rules. Ideally also provide an example which at first glance matches the rules, but fails if closely analysed.

Answer (score 0):

What you wanted to say is maybe: There are three groups of persons. 
Group 1: 75% of persons associates *only* with type A.
Group 2: 10% of persons associates *only* with type B.
Group 3: 15% of persons associates with both types.

total number of type A: 200*(0.75 + 0.15) = 180
total number of type B: 200*(0.10 + 0.15) = 50

There must be 230 entities of type A and type B.

Anyway, let’s forget about the number of entities for now.

```
import numpy as np

# two dimensional features: type A, type B
persons = np.zeros((200, 2))
persons[:180, 0] = 1
persons[150:, 1] = 1
np.random.shuffle(persons)
```

If distribution is fixed, then you can just shuffle persons id (sort of).